Controller Action with typenum
I have a problem in typo3 that I can't access my controller action via typenum. I use typo3 v12. I have the following in my routes
  - routePath: '/rss.xml'
    _controller: 'Article::feed'

das ruft folgende methode auf
public function feedAction(): ResponseInterface
{
    $articles = $this->getArticles();
    $this->view->assign('articles', $articles);
    $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse()
        ->withBody($this->streamFactory->createStream($this->view->render()));
     throw new PropagateResponseException($response, 200);
}

If I now call up domain.com/news/rss.xml, I get my XML view. How can I achieve the same result using the typenum?
I've already tried a bit but I always get NULL for the articles
In addition, instead of appending /rss.xml to the news page, is it possible to get the articles in XML format directly via domain.com/rss.xml?

So what is the code you tried that does not work?

[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'type') in [9818]]
pageNewsRSS = PAGE
pageNewsRSS.typeNum = 9818
pageNewsRSS.10 = USER
pageNewsRSS.10.userFunc = abc\def\Controller\ArticleController->feedAction
[global]

In general you would setup a new PAGE object with a typeNum different then 0.
A full example is in the docs: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.4/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/Rss/Index.html
In most cases there is actually no need for the condition, because a PAGE just kicks in if the typeNum matches.
If you have additional configuration code like overriding wraps from tt_content or plugin settings particular for this typeNum then I put a condition around like this (TYPO3 V12):
[request && request.getPageArguments()?.getPageType() == {$plugin.tx_news.rss.channel.typeNum}]

If you still want to have a speaking path for it, just add a static mapping inside your site configuration:
routeEnhancers:
   PageTypeSuffix:
     type: PageType
     map:
        rss.xml: 9818

For your typoscript to call an extbase controller action I would create a plugin and call it in typoscript like this:
feed_page = PAGE
feed_page {
   typeNum = 9818
   10 = USER
   10.userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
   10.extensionName= ExtensionName
   10.pluginName = PluginName
   10.vendorName = Vendor

Or directly injecting the plugin like in the news example.
